# undefined is not an object (evaluating abc.name)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a table in my database cold Apoet in my table field could name so I try to bring the name from the database but when I run the app this message appear
**undefined is not an object (evaluating abc.name)**

below my code

```
import React from 'react';
import  {useEffect}  from 'react';
import  {useState}  from 'react';
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { DataStore } from 'aws-amplify';
import { Apoet } from '../../models';

const ProductScreen = () => {

const route = useRoute();
console.log(route);

const {abc, setABC}= useState<Apoet | undefined>(undefined);

useEffect (()=>{
  if(!route.params?.id){
    return ;
  }
DataStore.query(Apoet,route.params.id).then(setABC)
},[route.params?.id]);

return (
<View>
   <Text>{abc.name} </Text>
</View>
)}
```

Comment: `abc` is `undefined`. `<Text>{abc.name} </Text>` is an error. You can't access `name` of `undefined. Initialize `abc`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `useState` is wrong, change with square brackets. Also be sure `route` changes as you expect otherwise it will be `undefined` again since your initial state value is also `undefined`

```
const [abc, setABC] = useState<Apoet | undefined>(undefined);
```

Comment: Thanks for you support 

whenever I changed the brackets to be square brackets this error appears

(**Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance in order to be iteracle, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method**)

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

You've incorrectly accessed the return value from the `useState` hook, it returns an array, not an object.

```
const {abc, setABC} = useState<Apoet | undefined>(undefined);
```

You also use an undefined initial value, so attempting to access into it will throw an error.

## Solution

Fix the return and use array destructuring assignment and use a valid initial value.

```
const [abc, setABC] = useState<Apoet>({});

...

<Text>{abc.name}</Text>
```

`abc` is now defined and can access a `name` property that will be undefined util the state is updated.

Or if you want to keep it allowed to be undefined, use a null check or Optional Chaining operator on the `name` property access.

Example:

```
const [abc, setABC] = useState<Apoet | undefined>();

...

<Text>{abc && abc.name}</Text>
or
<Text>{abc?.name}</Text>
```

Comment: Thanks for you support whenever I changed the brackets to be square brackets this error appears (**Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance in order to be iteracle, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method**)

Comment: @QasemAlbannay Interesting. The [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) hook certainly returns an array. Are you *sure* this 1 change causes that error? Can you try creating a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this error that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Thanks a lot it work now
 I just change type of page from .js to tsx and I put same code that you shared above finally work now

Comment: @QasemAlbannay Ah yeah, React Typescript files need the `*.ts(x)` file extension. Glad to help. Cheers and good luck.